# Can I fast travel a stolen car to my fortress?

Tags: mad-max

In *Mad Max* I've captured a scrap car and was wondering can I fast travel the car to my fortress and get the bounty on it, or will I just go there myself without the captured car?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can not.

If you try to fast travel while in a scrap car, I believe it will warn you that you will lose the car if you continue. I might remember wrong about the warning, but, either way, **you'll lose the car.**

Comment: I don't remember ever getting a warning, but I would just show up at the fast travel location in the magnum opus.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf I thought there was a warning, but maybe I just read that in a loading screen tip or somewhere else. Regardless if there is a warning or not though, I have tested it myself out of curiosity and of course, like you said, you lose the scrap car or any other car that's not magnum opus.

Comment: Yeah, it's one of those slight annoyances with an already massive game. Having to drive back and forth forever is just... ugh.